# What is "inappropriate"

Tags: discussion, inappropriate-content

In the [Role-playing games site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/), someone recently asked about possible usage of fictional D&D spell "Friends" which allows caster to charm someone for up to a minute, but such person will later remember the fact that it was coerced.

One of the comments was suggesting "Charm guard, tell him to give you the password and then kill him so he won't raise alarm after the spell wears off". I've suggested "get brief affection of bar wench without paying" (for which someone joked "how much affection can you get in one minute?")

My comment was marked (removed and also I received personal message) as "suggesting date rape and inappropriate".
Excuse me? First of all we are talking about absolutely fictional settings - no one is planning to murder anyone or do something to some bar girl. In RPG forum users discuss playing as vampires, werewolves, necromancers or other monster-eating babies; burning cities to the ground and sacrificing family members to Dark Gods -  because its all fictional...

Secondly - could someone explain me, why suggesting "murdering a guard" is fine but "getting attention from bar girl" is not. Would it be appropriate if it was from male waiter? Is there some sort of guide that I could read?

RPG aside - why discussion about assassins, thieves, murderers or arsonists is "OK" but about "rapists" (which I wasn't suggesting!) is not?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a discussion for the RPG Meta. I expect there will be quite a bit of variation among sites in the network as to what is borderline (in)appropriate.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I'll move it there.

Comment: Actually, I'll undelete, I would like to hear bit broader answer to that - including other medias.

Comment: It has been removed and personal message from moderator has been sent to me.

Comment: "or other monster-eating babies" dem some scary babies

Comment: [Here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/what-is-appropriate)'s the same question, asked on meta.rpg, and with an answer by [Tim Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post).

Comment: Two points on the comparison of discussing using magic to kill people and take their stuff vs discussing using magic to get laid. One, since there are (unfortunately) still more people who consider the IRL equivalent of the latter to be acceptable than the former, the former stays further in the realm of fiction, while the latter (despite your intentions) can cut closer to home. Second, a reader of rpg.SE is statistically less likely to have been murdered in the past than to have been raped, thus discussion of the former is less likely to produce IRL flashbacks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each site defines its own "inappropriate" things, something that is appropriate on one site might be inappropriate on other site.

So I fear there can't be a definitive answer to your question - you'll have to ask on each site meta to get real answer.

That said, there are ways to appeal flags/closing/deleting - this is done by flagging your own post, choosing "Other" and explain. This works even if the post is already deleted, then a moderator can undelete it.

Comment: I've asked the same question as I've posted here on RPG meta and the same moderator deleted it - I have no way now to flag it since it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kris if you have link to the question you can still see it and flag it, however since the moderator who deleted it also replied here, I believe it would be pointless.

Answer (score 7):

You left an inappropriate joke in a *comment* (not an answer), which was flagged as offensive. It was much more inappropriate than what you've paraphrased above, suggesting a spell would best be used in a manner which, when the joke's meaning was grasped, amounted to a suggestion that it would best be used as a magical date-rape drug.

I handled that flag by deleting the inappropriate comment and forgot about it.

The next day I came back to the same question for another reason and saw that you'd posted new similar comments. Less explicitly rape-y, but the same meaning nonetheless. Seeing that the comment deletion didn't send the message, I made it explicit that such material is not and will never be appropriate in a moderator message. My aim was to unambiguously communicate that you were not to repost such comments, and I hoped that would resolve the matter.

You replied to the moderator message defending your comments. At the same time, I noticed a post on meta.rpg.se inviting the community to debate the merits of your date-rape jokes.

I deleted that meta question as an inappropriate use of meta:

- It was repeating the material you were explicitly instructed to never post again on the site
- It asked where you could find a guide to what is appropriate, which you had already been provided in the warning
- It was in practice inviting community members to have a discussion about what counted as date rape, not a discussion that is appropriate for meta.rpg.se on a good day, let alone after being told plainly the answer to the question
- It was objecting to a warning from a moderator in the wrong venue

Normally I would allow a user who wanted to air their dirty laundry on meta to suffer the responses such a move would normally earn. But in this case, my concern was for the people who would have to read the inevitable descent into rape apologia, the same people whose usage of the site is protected by our zero-tolerance clause in the Be Nice policy. Not condoning a discussion that would inevitably attract rape apologist arguments required shutting that discussion down, so I deleted the meta question.

That's the sum of it. And this was a private warning that nobody but moderators would ever have known about otherwise, and would have been fully resolved by reading the warning, reading the Be Nice policy you were linked to, and simply refraining from posting such material in the future. There was no need to save face or recover the community's opinion of you, because it had been a private matter up until your attempt to create a public discussion of your warning.

For not taking the warning seriously, posting paraphrases of the material (which in no way hid their ultimate meaning) you were instructed to refrain from posting, and attempting to circumvent it, you then earned a short suspension and the instruction to use that time to fully consider the policy you were directed to read and the instructions you were given about future content submissions.

Either the suspension or the original warning can be appealed by contacting Stack Exchange directly via the **contact us** link below.

Comment: Ah, here's the missing context I was wondering about...

Comment: Never, in my entire time I wasn't trying to justify rape. EVER. You took my words out of context, which is the RPG make-believe world.
Now, to clarify: My first comment was "To get laid", which I deleted myself, because well... it was inappropriate, so I replaced it (after deleting the original) with "Getting affection from bar wench without paying". This is a make-believe world.  I've never justified rape and I feel myself personally offended by that suggestion.

Comment: @KrisWojcik You were justifying joking about using a spell to get laid by someone who otherwise would not be interested. That's rape. Ergo, a rape joke. (Being imaginary rape doesn't make it any less a real joke.) Later you joked about getting affection of the sexual variety, again from someone would wouldn otherwise. Still rape. And trying to say it's not rape, even well-meaning as I think you are, is the definition of "rape apologia". Please, please please please, read the link in your warning and *very carefully* consider why you were given a warning. Warnings are not handed out like candy.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: if I'd say "I put +10 charisma ring which makes the girl want me" would that be a date rape too? She wouldn't be interested in me otherwise.

Comment: @KrisWojcik Yes. RPG.se is not the place for talking about coercing women into sex. Not even fantasy coercion via magic. Actually, *especially* not fantasising about such coercion. We have users who are women who have to deal with that BS in real life all the time; we are not hosting it on a site were they come to get help with their fun-time escapist hobby.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie this is RPG. In games like "Vampire the Masquarade" there are even rules about enchanting someone to take them to bed using  Presence or Domination (or simply Appearance+ Empathy roll).

Comment: @KrisWojcik You said that in your objection to the moderator message, and it doesn't matter. What you do at your table, however rated-R, is your business. When you bring it onto RPG.se, it falls under our content policies. If you don't like that, you *are* welcome to not use the site.

Comment: You are moderator and I value your word, but please don't simply slap-close my question and suspend my account when I actually try to clarify the borders on the meta forum. If you read my original comment, there was NOT A SINGLE WORLD saying "sex" but "affection". Thats one. Two: we do discuss murders, thefts, arsons and demon worshiping that people can take much more offensive than "stealing someone's kiss", which my post had in mind.

Comment: I read your original comment, don't try to sugar-coat it. "Laid" means sex.

Comment: Your continued argument perplexes me. Do you want permission to make such jokes on the site? That permission is not going to be given. What are you hoping to get by arguing?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yes, and I've deleted the word "laid", since it indeed was inappropriate and instead I've said "getting affection". Different comment, different meaning.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I want to understand, what are the "appropriate" standards of RPG.se based not on your word ONLY, thats why I've asked on Meta RPG for general guides. I also want to understand what are the general stackexchange rules and are they are similar to yours where discussions about murder and theft are "OK" but about "tricking to get affection" (or even "laid") are not. Finally I'd like to hear appology about suggesting that I by any means justify real-world rape

Comment: You didn't delete the word at all, you left it in with a strikethrough, which was part of the joke. If you *want* the comment record public, this is effective. In addition to the Be Nice policy (which it seems you still have not read, as it answers your question about where the line is), you may want to read about the [Streisand Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect). You may also want to re-read the warnings, since they explain why fantasy violence in a game context is different from fantasy rape in a real joke. You can't just keep saying "please explain it" when it has been.

Comment: I've put it in strikeout as a joke, then I've deleted it. **I've**  deleted it myself. It is quite possible that You've done it as well while I was playing with the strikeout effect. That comment was inappropriate, and for that I've sincerely apologize - thats why I've replaced it with "getting affection". Without the strikeout to the word "laid". So unless thanks to some weird caching error we see different things on the page, we are talking about different things. But you do have problem not with that comment but with one about simply words "getting affection"

Comment: Secondly, its nothing about the violence: I wanted to discuss on RPG.Meta why we can say "the +5 Str will let me kill easier" but we can't "+5 Cha will let me get more girls interested in me". Does wearing fancy clothes, make-up or jewelry (real life equivalents of such magic rings) count as a coercing someone to have sex?

Comment: You're somewhat uninformed about what moderators can see about a comment's history. I'm going to assume you're misremembering rather than just lying. And I'm going to assume that you're going to read the things you've been instructed to read before you suspension is up, and consider this matter closed.

Comment: If I am mistaken about the final version of the comment, I appologise - I distinctly remember deleting the "laid" version and leaving the "affection" part only. You have all the proofs, which I can't see.

Comment: I've read the "Be nice"  post and I simply can't understand (and thats why I've posted it both here and on RPG.Meta" - to UNDERSTAND) why suggesting using anything for theft or murder is fine but using it in ever remotely sexual way is not. All I get in return is "because I say so". Is it the same reason (our case aside) that lets kids watch/play violent games but one mild erotic scene puts Mass Effect as 18+?

Comment: @KrisWojcik Yes. That is exactly it. The Stack's policies on acceptable content are derived from the wider norms of the society in which it operates: a society more comfortable with explicit violence than with explicit sexuality--and which regards sexual violence as an especially sensitive topic. **A Stack meta post is not a useful place to challenge societal norms.** (You'll also want to notice that SSD is not saying you were justifying real-life sexual assault--you're just defending making jokes about it--but that your meta posts effectively invite others to do so.)

Comment: @BESW I am simply trying to understand the fine borders here (which is my reason for posting it on RPG.meta): I.e. Is asking about attractiveness effect of +Charsima ring allowed? Or simply "pretty clothes"? Compliment? Smile? According to SSD its not... because in twisted logic "Making you more attractive is equal to coercing someone's mind which is equal to rape". Following that anything except saying "I would like to have intercourse with you" followed by "yes" is a rape.

Comment: @KrisWojcik The line is "Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. **will not be tolerated. At all.** (Those are just a few examples; **when in doubt, just don't.**)" If you have any doubt, don't do it. If you don't have a doubt, but it turns out that you were wrong, you'll get a friendly moderator message informing you not to do that. You will known the line by the pattern of "don't do that." Hopefully those will be few. But if you cannot follow moderation instruction, that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with a debate and/or moderator removing things you believe they shouldn't, first approach the moderator, in chat likely as it seems you have no relative answer to be able to draw their attention.

If you feel their response is unfair or not justified from a chat, then you can *flag it for moderator attention* for another moderator to check it.

Failing any of those things, then use the contact us link at the bottom of the pages to flag it with Stack Staff directly.

You can skip any of those options, even contact Stack directly, but I'd be inclined to give the benefit of the doubt first and chat with the moderator. We all make mistakes, and may just need you to put forward your side of the argument.